# What is the relation in sysfs, udev and user space

Tags: linux, driver, device, sysfs

I had a small confusion about creation of nodes, while writing a simple char driver. So I tried to find a way to make a node when my driver is inserted using

```
class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);
device_create(charClass, NULL, MKDEV(majorNumber, 0), NULL, DEVICE_NAME);
```

Upon reading about these apis, I came to know about sysfs, hal, bus, devfs, user space and hot plugging. Too many branches at the same time to follow. Can anybody simplify in the most laymen terms.Any simple analogy would be fine.